# A required TLS feature is missing. Error code: MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_REQUIRED_TLS_FEATURE_MISSING

Tags: bug, status-completed, ssl, firefox

Suddenly, today I am having issues connecting to https://stackoverflow.com/ from Firefox:

> An error occurred during a connection to stackoverflow.com. A required TLS feature is missing. Error code: MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_REQUIRED_TLS_FEATURE_MISSING

I checked https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=stackoverflow.com&s=151.101.65.69&latest and it seems it might be due to OCSP stapling:

> Supported, OCSP response not stapled

Comment: Also reported on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328821/295232).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't Connect with Firefox 67 / MOZILLA\_PKIX\_ERROR\_REQUIRED\_TLS\_FEATURE\_MISSING](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385590/cant-connect-with-firefox-67-mozilla-pkix-error-required-tls-feature-missing)

Comment: According to _X minutes ago_ I was the first. :)

Comment: Still present for me, also on meta, so I'm posting this from Edge :(

Comment: Since mine got closed I'll add here that as a workaround you can toggle `security.ssl.enable_ocsp_must_staple` setting to `false` in `about:config`

Comment: security.ssl.enable_ocsp_must_staple can be toggled in about:config as a temporary workaround.

Comment: chat.stackexchange.com is working, but stackexchange.com and other SO websites are not. Chrome works fine with every website

Comment: https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/1133787602027286529 -- they are working on rolling the change back

Comment: @billynoah It's a pity that in order to learn about this workaround *here*, one must first employ it ;)

Comment: Rollback complete: https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/1133791399189463040

Comment: Perhaps this quote "To summarize: This is all a big mess. Both Apache and Nginx have OCSP Stapling implementations that are essentially broken. As long as you’re using either of those then enabling Must-Staple is a reliable way to shoot yourself in the foot and get into trouble" from a 2017 blog post https://blog.hboeck.de/archives/886-The-Problem-with-OCSP-Stapling-and-Must-Staple-and-why-Certificate-Revocation-is-still-broken.html applies also her ...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We have worked with our CDN provider to roll back a change that was made enforcing OCSP Must-Staple. Firefox should be back in business, sorry for the interruption. To keep up to date follow our StackStatus twitter account:

https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/1133791399189463040

Comment: Looks like it worked, I'm posting this from Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix (after all, in a certificate issue in a large deployment!). It seems you switched from a one week old Letsencrypt with must-staple enabled to an older Digicert without must-staple (but with stapling). I'm just curious: a) Why did this kick in after a week and not earlier? b) Why did you roll back instead of reissuing LE without the must-staple option? (Though I suspect that for b the answer is that this was faster and more foolproof to solve the problem)

Comment: If only canary deployments and BrowserShots were a thing.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen the LE cert was issued a week ago, but first deployed this morning. Previous testing on a dev cert indicated ocsp would work seamlessly, but this cert was bigger and more complicated, and involved a different process to deploy. Rolling back was the fast option, but I am currently also getting a safer cert to roll forward as we speak.

Comment: For a minute I was really worried that Mozilla was going to have 2 cert issues in as many months (armagadd-on 2.0 and this).

Comment: As of march 2021 I am having this issue with a certificate issued by CertCloud RSA TLS CA.

Comment: This issue has come back!!