# Can't Connect with Firefox 67 / MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_REQUIRED_TLS_FEATURE_MISSING

Tags: support, bug

Today when trying to connect here with Firefox 67 I am getting the following error:

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> An error occurred during a connection to stackoverflow.com. A required
>   TLS feature is missing. Error code:
>   MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_REQUIRED_TLS_FEATURE_MISSING

[image]

Tried on a (much) older version of Firefox I have on another computer and it connected fine.  Other browsers also connect fine.  If I toggle `security.ssl.enable_ocsp_must_staple` setting to `false` in about:config this also allows a successful connection.

There is Q&A here regarding this issue: https://support.mozilla.org/gl/questions/1149911 which indicates that "*there is a problem with the server's OCSP response*".

Is this a server side bug or a Firefox bug?

Comment: As of march 2021 I am having this issue with a certificate issued by CertCloud RSA TLS CA.